# Is WinForms GUI?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have read that winforms apps are programs with graphical user interface. Is that correct? I thought winforms are just API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GUI(Graphical User Interface) is the interface the user uses to communicate with your application. So yes, WinForms is a GUI API indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Winforms is plattform for GUI design for local programs the same way that ASP.net is a plattform for GUI on web applications.

An alternative would be console programs that execute in the command console and only use text output or services that have no GUI at all.

Answer (score 0):

WinForms in an API for desktop GUI. It includes many different controls, such as buttons, test boxes, list boxes etc... Any common control that a typical window would have.

Answer (score 0):

Yes... It is API!
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) Says: "Windows Forms is the name given to the graphical application programming interface (API) included as a part of Microsoft .NET Framework, providing access to native Microsoft Windows interface elements by wrapping the extant Windows API in managed code."

Answer (score 0):

I think you quite confused because, Window Forms Applications are not GUIs rather Windows Forms applications also contains Graphical Interfacing.

Answer (score 0):

WinForm is a kind of GUI application.